# PG Upgrade Errors

Tags: pgadmin-4, postgresql-12

I have upgraded Postgres to 12.1, PostGIS to 3.0 and PGAdmin to 4.15. Running queries and using PGAdmin GUI results in some error messages:

1. ERROR:  column rel.relhasoids does not exist
   LINE 1: SELECT rel.relhasoids AS has_oids
2. Error retrieving data from the server: INTERNAL SERVER ERROR 
   String indices must be integers

What am I missing that will solve these errors?

Answer (score 4):

I needed to remove the server from PGAdmin and re-add it.

Comment: this solved my problem, I spent hours looking for a solution.