# PGAdmin can not view data, missing FROM-clause entry for table "rel"

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I am using PgAdmin4 with version 7.4. From today suddenly I can not view table or rows and getting this error for all tables.

```
missing FROM-clause entry for table "rel"
LINE 8: ...ER JOIN pg_catalog.pg_constraint con ON con.conrelid=rel.oid
```

Getting this error whenever I click `view data` button or run query like `Select * from my_table`. Previously I did not have any issue accessing the data. How do I solve this?

Comment: Sounds like you are using an too-new version of pgAdmin with a too-old version of PostgreSQL.

Comment: @jjanes yes ubuntu updated some apps this morning. Guess I have to reinstall pgadmin with earlier version

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Downgraded from pgadmin4 7.4 to 7.3 and got it working again.

```
apt-get install pgadmin4-server=7.3
apt-get install pgadmin4-desktop=7.3
```

**Edited**

pgadmin4 v7.5 was released on July 27, 2023. Upgraded from pgadmin4 7.4 to 7.5 and also got it working again.

Comment: Thank you, I had the same issue and I have run those two commands. Now I am getting new error message "string indices must be integers", any thought?

Comment: Have not seen this error yet. Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59094036/pg-upgrade-errors helps (remove server from pgAdmin and readd it). Some other sources mention restarting the pgadmin4 process.

Comment: I have managed to solve the issue (string indices must be integers) by upgrading my PostgreSQL to version 11.

Comment: This issue occured to me after PGADMIN upgrade which had to be performed when I upgraded Ubuntu from 20.04 to 22.04